# issue while converting Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

**Error 2902    The type 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.PropertyEditing.PropertyValue' exists in both 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.Windows.Design.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.dll'**

How can i resolve it?